# Forcing CollectionChanged Event of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

**Is there any way to force the CollectionChanged Event of an ObservableCollection to fire?**

Unfortunately the interface I'm using for the collection items does not belong to me so I can't edit it.

```
public ObservableCollection<iNotMyInterface> VarHandles
    {
        get => _varHandles;
        private set => SetField(ref _varHandles, value);
    }
```

I have a method that fires if the .value property of my interface changes though which also sends me the updated object.

```
public void Notify(iNotMyInterface updatedObject)
    {
        
    }
```

**I tried replacing the item in the collection:`VarHandles[VarHandles.IndexOf(_oldHandle)] = _newHandle;` but this doesn't fire the event.**

I have also tried:`VarHandles.Remove(_oldHandle); VarHandles.Add(_newHandle);` this does fire the event and update my UI but it changes the object position in the WPF Datagrid making it difficult to keep track of. I could organize the collection every time but it just seems messy.

**I'd like to just use the OnPropertyChanged method from the INotifyPropertyChanged interface my class implements but that doesn't seem to work either.**

```
public void Notify(iNotMyInterface updatedObject)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("VarHandles");
    }
```

Am I using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface incorrectly? It works fine with other class properties that are of type bool or double.

```
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string _propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_propertyName));

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T _field, T _value, string _propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(_field, _value)) return false;

        _field = _value;
        OnPropertyChanged(_propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Have you tried recreating the observable collection? `this.VarHandles = new ObservableCollection<iNotMyInterface>(this.VarHandles);`

Comment: Does your class implement iNotMyInterface?

Comment: It is unclear which event you are actually interested in. Replacing an item in the collection would of course fire the CollectionChanged event, but not the PropertyChanged event, while removing and adding an element would fire both two times.

Answer (score 0):

Revising this after a year, a better way to accomplish this would be to create a Model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and contains a property of type iNotMyInterface. Then have the ObservableCollection become of a list of that Model.

Something like so:

```
public sealed class VarHandleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private iNotMyInterface _data;
    public iNotMyInterface Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => SetField(ref _data, value, nameof(Data));
    }

    //Any Other Properties Needed
}
```

Then Modify

`ObservableCollection<iNotMyInterface> VarHandles { get; private set; }`

In the original ViewModel to

`ObservableCollection<VarHandleModel> VarHandles { get; private set; }`

So the Modify method can simply replace the iNotMyInterface property in that ViewModel and any UI bound to that property will automatically update!

If there is a need to make the model more open ended it can always be opened to generics and iNotMyInterface can be of type T.